# Autogrow Alert/Job not working, WMI(FileName) not found

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, jobs, alerts

im trying to set up an alarm that notifies me when an auto grow is happening,im using this link material to create everything
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3128/monitor-sql-server-database-file-growth-with-wmi-alerts/
altough i made everything exactly like in that post, i receive this message when i try to simulate an autogrow situation,

Unable to start execution of step 1 (reason: Variable WMI(FileName) not found).  The step failed.

The job fails, and i dont know how to fix the WMI part so it takes it correctly,any tips on how to do it?

Comment: That MSSQLTips.com page refers to a previous tip -- https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3095/monitor-sql-server-databases-changes-using-wmi-alerts/ -- in which they did a step to enable token replacement. That might be required even for the tip you are working on, even though they don't explicitly call it out.